# How to create a custom annotated validation that has a param in spring boot?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, validation, customvalidator

Is it possible to pass a value when using a custom annotated validation? The logic is different depending on the param value. In the example below, the chill room may require the key-value pairs to include "snack" : "" with max length 10, min length 1 **similar to the @Size(min = 1, max = 10).** I'm implementing the ConstraintValidator and set up the interface.

i.e.

```
@ConcertValidation(dressingRoom = "chill")
private List<Map<String, String>> json;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the interface for the validator, include:

```
//default code
pubilc @interface ConcertValidation{
    // default code
    String dressingRoom() default "";
}
```

In the validator class, you must initialize the params you want to pass to use them in your logic for the isValid() method;

```
// global variables
private String dressingRoom;

@Override
public void initialize(ConcertValidation concertValidationConstraint){
    this.dressingRoom = concertValidationConstraint.dressingRoom();
}
```

Whenever you use the custom annotation validation, just pass the params.

```
@ConcertValidation(dressingRoom = "chill")
private List<Map<String, String>> json;
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside the `initialize` method of the `ConstraintValidator` implementation, you can capture the value from annotation. For example:

```java
class ConcertValidator implements ConstraintValidator<ConcertValidation, List<Map<String, String>>> {

    String dressingRoom;

    @Override
    public void initialize(ConcertValidation constraintAnnotation) {
        dressingRoom = constraintAnnotation.dressingRoom();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(List<Map<String, String>> value, ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
        boolean isValid = false;
        //TODO implement your logic depending on dressingRoom value
        return isValid;
    }
}
```